# findbugs-maven-plugin doesn't find circular dependencies

Tags: maven, findbugs

I just noticed that the findbugs maven plugin doesn't find circular dependencies while the eclipse plugin does. Even if i explicitly say it in the include filter. This is the POM:

```
<build
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <xmlOutput>false</xmlOutput>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <includeFilterFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/findbugs-include.xml</includeFilterFile>
                <excludeFilterFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

Eclipse plugin shows 11 bugs in 5 categories. One pattern is "CD_CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY". The maven plugin finds all of them too except this circular dependency. So I ask myself why this is the case and is it possible to cahnge this?. Another question is: Are there any other Bugs that can't be found with the maven plugin? If there are bugs that can't be detected it ahould be listed somewhere...

EDIT: Another Bug that the maven plugin doesn't find/report: IMA_INEFFICIENT_MEMBER_ACCESS

Comment: Which version of findbugs does Eclipse use? The version in the findbugs-maven-plugin can seen here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. The versions are the same. As you can see in the POM, maven plugin is 2.5.4 which uses FindBugs 2.0.3 and this is the version the eclipse plugin has

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Spotbugs (successor of findbugs), and eventually ended up in having 2 separate configurations, one that does the regular checks, one that does ONLY the circular dependency check.

The main difference is for the CD check, besides the classdirs etc, I set the following params (using gradle)

```
visitors = ['FindCircularDependencies']
extraArgs = ['-nested:true']
```